# Can't bind datatable Value to datagridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datatable, datagridview

[Im using Vs 2019 Winform C# seems like i cannot customize my datagrid  only showing specific  columns heres the code image seems like out of range but the data property is correct ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snDN8.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `DataGridView` control's columns by using the `Columns collection`

first you add this code:  `dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1;`
then

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Id", "Id");
```

Comment: Holyyy!!! Thank you sir it worked!! <3 <3